# Ошибки подключения базы данных и Tomcat 8.0

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

Я написала сервлет с jsp. По нажатию кнопки на страничке jsp начинает выполнятся метод, который заходит в базу данных mssql сервера, берет оттуда данные простеньким select и выводит на следующей странице jsp. 
Драйвер использую jtds.
Файл из папки SSO уже лежит в `jre/bin` и в system32.
Библиотека jtdS также в `tomcat/lib`.

- Если запускать класс, который ходит за данными, с помощью метода `main`, без участия tomcat. То все исправно работает.
- Если же варник класть в папку к tomcat и потом запускать через браузер, возможны варианты:

  1. Все работает, но один или два раза.
  2. Не работает вовсе. Ошибки две:

     > java.sql.SQLException: Не удается открыть базу данных "Majong", запрашиваемую именем входа. Не удалось выполнить вход.

     или

     > java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: SSO Failed: Native SSPI library not loaded. Check the java.library.path system property

Сначала, были моменты, когда оно работало или не работало. Такое впечатление, что при втором входе, драйвера базы данных были заняты, не давали подключатся. Но потом перестало вовсе заходить. 
Прошу совета специалистов. Буду очень благодарна за помощь.

Так контроллер получает данные с jsp

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    int periodNum = Integer.valueOf(request.getAttribute("periodNum2").toString());
    int firstNum = Integer.valueOf(request.getAttribute("firstNum2").toString());
    Map<String, Card> map = new HashMap();
    // fill map

    new SelectCard().execute(map);
    request.getRequestDispatcher(PAGE_RESULT).forward(request, response);
}
```

Из пула берется соединение. Пул много раз проверялся в обычных приложениях.

```
  public class SelectCard {
   protected static DBConnectionPool pool = DBConnectionPool.getInstance();     

public void execute(Map<String, Card> map){
    Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
    if (connection == null) {
        System.out.println("Can't receive connection!");
        LogSingleton.appendLog("Can't receive connection!");
    }
    String SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT * from Majong.dbo.Cards where id = %d";

    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet resultSet= null;
    String query = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, SELECT_QUERY,
            map.get("west").getId()
    );
    try {
        stmt = connection.createStatement(); // tomcat утверждает, что в этом месте NullPointerException
        resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while(resultSet.next()){
            // work with result
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if(resultSet != null){
                resultSet.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pool.freeConnections(connection);
    }
}
}
```

И сам пул

```
public class DBConnectionPool {

static private String URL ;
private static String user = "";
private static String password = "";
private static int maxConn;
private final String DRIVER_NAME = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
private final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/Majong;";
private final int MAX_COUNT = 3;

PrintWriter log;
static private List<Connection> freeConnections = new ArrayList<>();
static private DBConnectionPool instance = new DBConnectionPool();

private DBConnectionPool() {
    this.URL = JDBC_URL ;
    this.maxConn = MAX_COUNT;
    loadDrivers();
}

private void loadDrivers() {
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver());
        System.out.println("Registered JDBC driver ");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Can't register JDBC driver");
    }
}

public static synchronized DBConnectionPool getInstance() {

    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DBConnectionPool();
    }

    return instance;
}


public synchronized Connection getConnection() {

    Connection con = null;
    if (!freeConnections.isEmpty()) {
        con = (Connection)freeConnections.get(freeConnections.size()-1);
        freeConnections.remove(con);

        try {
            if (con.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("Removed bad connection ");
                con = getConnection(); // Try again recursively
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Removed bad connection ");
            con = getConnection(); // Try again recursively
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Removed bad connection ");
            con = getConnection();// Try again recursively
        }
    } else {
        con = newConnection();
    }

    return con;
}
private Connection newConnection() {

    Connection con = null;
    try {
        if (user == null) {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
        } else {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, user, password);
        }
    }  catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return con;
}
public synchronized void freeConnections(Connection con) {

    if ( (con != null) && (freeConnections.size() <= maxConn) ) {
        freeConnections.add(con);
    }
}
public synchronized void released() {
    Iterator allConnections = freeConnections.iterator();

    while (allConnections. hasNext()) {
        Connection con = (Connection) allConnections.next();

        try {
            con.close();
            System.out.println("Closed connection for pool");
        }

        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't close connection for pool");
        }

    }

    freeConnections.clear(); }
```

}